# Best way to get user messages in cassandra cql?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I'm trying to create a chat app with use the Cassandra database. so I want to get messages that send between to users (private chat) . so I want to get the best and optimal way to do CQL query? What are your idea?

my user message table structure.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Everything that has been said is true.

- Based you data model on your queries
- DS2020 on academy.datastax.com is a full fledge course to explain how to do.

Now regarding your sample chat here is some proposition

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sample_chat;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sample_chat (
  fromuser    text,
  touser      text,
  message_id  timeuuid,
  body        text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((fromuser, touser), message_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (msg_time DESC);

INSERT INTO sample_chat(fromuser, touser, message_id, body) VALUES('Cedrick', 'Hasan', now(), 'Hi Hasan do you like Cassandra');
INSERT INTO sample_chat(fromuser, touser, message_id, body) VALUES('Hasan', 'Cedrick', now(), 'Yeah Cassandra rocks');
INSERT INTO sample_chat(fromuser, touser, message_id, body) VALUES('Cedrick', 'Hasan', now(), 'Take ds220 and give us some feedback');

select fromuser, touser, body from sample_chat;
```

Rational:

- You want to retrieve a chat based on `fromuser` and `touser` and as such this is a good partition key. Chat between 2 users should not have more than 100.000 lines which is the recommended max number of rows for a partition.
- You want your items to be ordered by time with latest in first (display only last messages in the chat). You want your messages to be unique. As such `timeuuid` is a good type for `message_id` you can extract time from it easily and it ensures unicity.
- You want to avoid using `time` as a column name or any term that collide with existing keyword of cql.

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra, the table design should be done based on the query/queries that you are going to execute; in this case, how are you going to request the data? based on the `fromuser` or the `touser` column, both?

Datastax Academy has the course [DS220](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds220) that can be a good starting point to learn data modeling for Cassandra

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra, you have to work on data model part and optimise your queries based on Datastax or Cassandra recommendations. As per you app you should also work on Cassandra configurations part what would be good for heavy write and read. To get good performance on your app you should consider not only database part but also need to consider OS, network etc.